# Laravel + Vue tutorial, not working as it should

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I need some help.

I am doing this tutorial https://www.udemy.com/share/102itcAkocdl9XTQ==/ and its not working as it should and not sure what I am doing wrong.

file structure
- components
 - App.vue
- views
 - Start.vue
- app.js
- bootstrap.js
- router.js

App.vue

```
 <template>
 <div>App component
 <router-view></router-view>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
 name: "App"
    }

</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Start.vue

```
<template>
 <div>Start View</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 name: "Start"
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import router from './router';
import App from './components/App';
require('./bootstrap');

const app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',

 components: {
 App
    },

 router,
});
```

router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Start from './views/Start';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

export default new VueRouter({
 mode: 'history',

 routes: [{
 path: '/',
 name: 'home',
 component: Start,
    }]
});
```

Please help if you see what i am doing wrong. The Start view is not showing, when it is apparently supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `app.js`, try creating the instance like this

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

Comment: You are an absolute legend. It worked. I dont know what it means, but once i get to know the framework better i am sure i will understand it. I appreciate your help Rijosh

Comment: Than you. The `render` is defining the root component of your application. All other components will come under this. You can see the structure in the `devtools`.